# what to do if it's not direct sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppose $X=Y+Z$ is Banach, $Y$ and $Z$ are closed subspaces. I want to show there exists $\alpha>0$ such that $\forall x \in X, \exists$ $y \in Y$ and $z \in Z$ such that  $x=y+z$ and $\|y\|+\|z\| \le \alpha\|x\|$.

If that is direct sum, I can define $T:Y \times Z \to X$ by $T(y,z)=y+z$. It can be easily checked that $Y \times Z$ is Banach, $T$ is linear, bounded and bijective. Hence, by inverse mapping theorem, $T^{-1}$ exists and is bounded. Then we can take $\alpha$ to be $\|T^{-1}\|$, $y, z$ to be the unique decomposition, and it's done.

But what to do if $Y\bigcap Z \ne\{0\}$ in general?

I tried to define $T:(Y/Y\bigcap Z) \times (Z/Y\bigcap Z) \to X$ by $T([y],[z])=y+z$. Then this map is linear, bijective and between two Banach spaces. Then I ran into trouble showing it's continuous (I wanted to apply inverse mapping theorem).

Am I on the right track?